# Interpretation of 3:123

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation

In Surah Ali Imran 3:123 it says:

> And already had Allah given you victory at [the battle of] Badr while
>   you were few in number. **Then fear Allah ; perhaps you will be
>   grateful.**

The word by word translation from Quran.com of the phrase in bold is:

So fear - Allah SWT - So that you may - (be) grateful

What is the meaning of this phrase I don't understand. What is the relation between fear and being grateful.

Being grateful is being grateful for something of the past. But fear is, as far as I know (but CMIIW), is fear to something that may happen in the future. So how come fearing something makes somebody grateful? What's the relation? Can anyone explain on this.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by CMIIW?

Comment: @Medi1Saif  '**C**orrect **M**e **I**f **I**'m **W**rong'

Answer (score 1):

Allah says in the the Qur'an:

> وَلَقَدْ نَصَرَكُمُ اللَّهُ بِبَدْرٍ وَأَنتُمْ أَذِلَّةٌ فَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَشْكُرُونَ
>
> <sup>- [Surah Ali 'Imran, Verse 123](https://quran.com/3/123)</sup>

[Maududi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abul_A'la_Maududi) translates the verse as:

> *Indeed Allah had already succoured you in the battle of Badr when you were in a much weaker position,* ***therefore you should refrain from showing ingratitude towards Allah: it is expected that you will be grateful now.***
>
> <sup>- [Tafsir al-Maududi](http://www.englishtafsir.com/quran/3/index.html)</sup>

According to this translation, the phrase means:

**Since Allah helped you win in the Battle of Badr when you were vastly outnumbered,**

- you should refrain from showing ingratitude towards Allah
- it is expected that you will be grateful to Allah for everything

There are many more [translations](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/3/123/default.htm) which you could view in order to help understand the phrase, some suggest have fear in Allah so you may show Him gratefulness and others suggest be mindful of Allah but all of these translations suggest that:

- Stay steadfast in the religion and observe it in piety and fear of Allah
- Then you will be grateful to Allah (i.e remaining steadfast in the religion and observe it strictly suggests you will be rewarded with Paradise and then you will thank Allah for that.)

Comment: First let me verify, is **"fearing Allah SWT"** and **"being grateful to Allah SWT"** the exact same thing? Or are they two different kind of things?

Comment: In this verse they are not the same thing but fearing Allah precedes being grateful to Allah.

Comment: Does that imply that you cannot be grateful to Allah SWT if you haven't feared Allah?

Comment: Yes since fearing Allah is obligatory as verse [3:175](https://quran.com/3/175) suggests '**So fear them not, but fear Me, if you are [indeed] believers.**'

Comment: I'm not quite understand. Fearing Allah is obligatory. Yes that is correct. But where and how does THAT implies that you cannot be grateful to Allah SWT unless you fear Him? Since those two, as you said, are two different things

Comment: Fearing Allah means you would perform your religious duty which means you would be grateful to Allah. If you don't fear Allah, then your not follow the religion correctly and therefore how can you be grateful to Allah?

Comment: If you are grateful to Allah SWT, you would perform religious duties. That I agree. But if a person performs religious duties, does it always mean that that person is grateful to Allah SWT?

Comment: So long as they're not commiting sins, yes?

Comment: Is it not possible for someone to just perform routine religious duties without actually having any feeling of gratefulness at all towards God in his heart?

Comment: If they're performing it properly then they will feel grateful.

Comment: "If they're performing it properly then they will feel grateful" so here are you implying that  the action (of performing religious duties properly) comes first in order for someone to feel grateful to Allah SWT?

Comment: How else would you feel grateful to Allah without performing any religious duty?

Comment: Which religious duties are you recommending specifically   that can produce a feeling of gratitude in oneself?

Comment: You must do there obligatory ones like salah but have a good character and personality.

Comment: Let's take Salah as an example then.  When or What part or which position particularly in Salah do you think that is biggest in creating the feeling of gratitude in you?